# Why is the Levi-decomposition not available in positive characteristic?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, positive-characteristic

I am learning about Lie-Algebras and I came across a proof of the Levi-decomposition.
Can somebody tell why the Lie-Algebra has to be over a field of characteristic $0$? Why does it fail for positive characteristic?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is, that there are counterexamples in characteristic $p$, see for example this [MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22118/are-there-reasonable-criteria-for-existence-non-existence-of-levi-factors-or-t).
Moreover, most results of classical Lie algebra theory fail in characteristic $p>0$, such as Lie's Theorem, Cartan's criterion for semisimplicity (non-degenerate Killing form), almost all results for representations of semisimple Lie algebras, the classification of semisimple Lie algebras and so on.

It is more difficult to give a sufficient answer, why. Of course, many arguments involving linear algebra fail for characteristic $p$, e.g., arguments using the trace. A summary can be found, for example, in this post:

[If the field of a vector space weren't characteristic zero, then what would change in the theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2341854/if-the-field-of-a-vector-space-werent-characteristic-zero-then-what-would-chan/2342055)

Whitehead's lemma, saying that the $H^1(L,M)=0$ for semisimple Lie algebras of characteristic zero also fails in characteristic $p$.

In characteristic zero, the short exact sequence

$$
{\displaystyle 0\rightarrow \mathrm {rad} ({\mathfrak {g}})\rightarrow {\mathfrak {g}}\,{\xrightarrow {\varphi }}\,{\mathfrak {g}}/\mathrm {rad} ({\mathfrak {g}})\rightarrow 0}
$$

splits, because $\mathfrak{g}/{\rm rad}(\mathfrak{g})$ is semisimple and Whitehead's Lemma. Levi's Theorem
is a simple consequence of this fact. As said, this fact fails in characteristic $p>0$.